# Problem running python code on broswerstack

Tags: python, automation, pycharm, pytest, browserstack

Background

- trying to do automation tests using python selenium - pytest framework /pycharm IDE
- problem - It runs absolutely fine, when running the tests on my local machine by giving executable path as my local chrome-path (i.e) chrome-driver
- However, there is a requirement that I need to run these tests on browser-stack via Jenkins remotely on a daily bases. So I have added the code for browser-stack, but it doesn't work
- Error message - when i execute the code -following error message i get, any suggestions to help to fix this problem, would be great.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pytest
from ZProjects.AutomationS.Pages.utils import Utils
from ZProjects.AutomationS.Pages.loginPage import loginpageMethods
from ZProjects.AutomationSynapse.Pages.logoutPage import logoutpageMethods, logoutpageLocators

@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.NORMAL)
def test_setup():
    global driver
    desired_cap = {
        'browser': 'Chrome',
        'browser_version': '79.0',
        'os': 'Windows',
        'os_version': '10',
        'resolution': '1024x768',
        'name': 'Bstack-[Python] Sample Tests'
    }

    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='https://jpopiiiiii@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/fg/hub',
        desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=Utils.chromePath) # commented this line
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Chrome Browser Launched successfully - Setup - Passed")

@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.BLOCKER)
def test_login_1():
    driver.get(Utils.url)
    login = loginpageMethods(driver)
    login.enter_username(Utils.username)
    login.enter_password(Utils.password)
    login.click_login()
    time.sleep(50)
    print("User logged in Successfully - Passed")
```

---

### error message -for first test

```
self = <urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool object at 0x0000014F3C424DA0>
method = 'POST', url = '/wd/hub/session'
body = '{"capabilities": {"firstMatch": [{}], "alwaysMatch": {}}, "desiredCapabilities": {"browser": "Chrome", "browser_version": "79.0", "os": "Windows", "os_version": "10", "resolution": "1024x768", "name": "Bstack-[Python] Sample Tests"}}'
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic amVubmlmZXJwYWlzMjozeHN6bml3bXNHcVFRejNqblhvaQ==', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'User-Agent': 'selenium/3.141.0 (python windows)'}
retries = Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
redirect = False, assert_same_host = False
timeout = <object object at 0x0000014F39E8EDD0>, pool_timeout = None
release_conn = True, chunked = False, body_pos = None
```

---

### error for second test

```
@allure.severity(allure.severity_level.BLOCKER)
    def test_login_1():
>       driver.get(Utils.url)
E       NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Test_Results_General_Scenarios_Module.py:50: NameError
```

Answer (score 0):

You can review the BrowserStack documentation for executing tests in Python from the link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/python#getting-started

Also, configure capabilities as mentioned in the link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities?tag=selenium-2-3